# Have a money order delivered to you in US

Tags: money-order

**In short:**

Are there any financial institutions in US that take online orders to post an unused money order of requested amount to your address?

**Detailed:**

I have to send a money order along with some documents in post. Usually, I just go to the post office and get the money order and put it in an envelope along with my documents. Due to current situation related to COVID-19, I was hesitant to do any of the these steps in person. I was wondering if there is a way to have a money order delivered to me, or any other way that does not require contact with others.

Comment: Do you have a checking account? Many will let you have a check drawn on your account mailed from the bank to whatever payee you like through their bill pay process.

Comment: How critical is it that the funds transfer be by money order? For example, could you transfer funds using internet banking?

Comment: I will give them a call to ask the same question. I just realized they even are picky on the money order itself and ask it to be from post office.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to contact the Post office and ask about their procedures. My local post office has made modifications to their procedures and layout to protect customers and workers. They may ask for you to follow specific modified instructions regarding forms of payment and ID.

An alternative is to have a trusted family member be the go between. This might be an option if you are in one of the more vulnerable groups.

Please make sure the reason for the money order isn't a scam. Once the money order is sent you have a very  limited ability to get the money back.